# Circular dependency error while trying to add reference

Tags: c#

In my solution, there are 2 projects: Helper and Service.Helper project has a reference to the service

In the helper project I have

**Culture Helper**

```
 public static class CultureHelper
    {
    public static Location GetLocationBasedOnCulture(string cultureName)
            {
                Location location = Location.UK;
                if (cultureName == Constants.CultureConstants.Italy)
                {
                    location = Location.Italy;
                }
                return location;
            }
    }
```

**Culture Constants:**

```
public static class CultureConstants
    {
        public static readonly string UK = "en-GB";
        public static readonly string Italy = "it-IT";

    }
```

In the Service I am trying to add this method:

```
public Enum DetermineLocation()
        {
            var culture = CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture();
            Location location = CultureHelper.GetLocationBasedOnCulture(culture);
            return location;
        }
```

I am trying to add a method to the service that uses the static CultureHelper class but I am unable to add a reference to helper in service as it will lead to circular dependency. How do I go ahead with this. Is creating an interface going to solve this problem and how.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) at the moment in what way `CultureHelper` is depending on `Service` at all, and so not clear in what way a circular dependency is arising.

Comment: You need third helper project for this. You can not add reference in such way. One project should add reference to other and other can not add reference of that project which has already refereed that project.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha - you *can* have circular dependencies between .NET assemblies but its far from the norm and I'd usually recommend against it. (Many of the central assemblies have such cross-references)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have another class- FileHelper which makes use of the service and so I added a reference to service to be able to use it in the FileHelper class. So it is not Culturehelper that depends on Service but another class in the Helper project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not add reference of a project in that project which has already refereed your first project. Say

you have two project **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**
now you add reference of **ProjectB** in **ProjectA** 
when you try to add reference of **ProjectA** in **ProjectB** you will get circular dependency as you are point one project to one another.

So to solve this problem you should create **ProjectC** that add reference to **ProjectB** and finally you can add reference of **ProjectC** in **ProjectA**

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a third project (C) with types that are common for project A and B, and let A and B reference C.

2) Move types in B that depends on types in A to A (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

If your projects do genuinely need to cross-reference each other, and you're unable to use the other suggestions to restructure, here's a demo of how you can achieve mutual cross-referencing.

In Visual Studio, create a new Solution and add a normal Class Library called `A`. Leave `Class1` alone.

Create a Shared Project and name it `Proto_B`. Add a class called `Class1` and change its namespace declaration to be `B`.

Create a Class Library called `B_NonA`. Delete `Class1`. Add a shared project reference to `Proto_B`, and change the settings so that its default namespace is `B` and it emits the `B` assembly. Add a reference from project `A` to project `B_NonA`.

Create a Class Library called `B_A`. Delete `Class1`. Add a shared project reference to `Proto_B`, and change the settings so that its default namespace is `B` and it emits the `B` assembly. Also set it to include a conditional compilation symbol `HASA` for all configurations. Add a reference from project `B_A` to project `A`.

All of the code can now compile. The assemblies that you would distribute would be those emitted by the `A` and `B_A` projects.

You never add code to `B_A` or `B_NonA`, only to `ProtoB`. Where code has to actually make use of `A` assembly features, that code should be wrapped in an `#if HASA` block.

In this toy example, `A.Class1` is:

```
namespace A
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static B.Class1 _otherB = new B.Class1();
    }
}
```

And `B.Class1` in `ProtoB` is:

```
namespace B
{
    public class Class1
    {
#if HASA
        private static A.Class1 _otherA = new A.Class1();
#endif
    }
}
```

One obvious downside to this approach is that it leads to longer build times since any change in `B` requires `B` to be rebuilt twice with a build of `A` performed in between.

Answer (score 0):

If your using nopcommerce, look into the event publisher.

Register your event in the core nop files, then build your event handler in the plugin with the circular issue where you need to pass data back.
When you publish the event from Plugin A, you pass objects etc through that and they will be available in plugin B :)

From nopcommerce:

> To publish an event a developer will need to obtain an instance of IEventPublisher and call the Publish method with the appropriate event data.
> To listen for an event the developer will want to create a new implementation of the generic IConsumer interface. Once a new consumer implementation has been created nopCommerce uses reflection to find and register the implementation for event handling.

I'm sure other systems have something similar, and this is my favorite way to get around these issues